# Slow shutdown of VB ocx file with MSVBVM60.dll after converting from VBscript to JScript

Tags: vbscript, vb6, internet-explorer-11, jscript, ocx

We have an application that currently works on IE browsers till IE10version.
We have a challange to move towards IE11 as VB support is removed from IE in standard mode.
We had lots of VB scripts that were converted to JScripts. The application also loads VB6 active x components.
After conversion from VB script to JScript, the application runs fine except in places where VB6 active x components are being loaded.
The application crashes every alternate time with "out of memory" issue and does not load the ocx file.
Note: this happens every alternate time.
I used ProcMon tool to see what was happening. I see when the active x component is loaded, the ocx file is loaded and another dll MSVBVM60.dll is also loaded. when the active x component is Shutdown, the MSVBVM60 is also cleaned up along with that.
The next time when we try to load the active x component, the ocx file and MSVBVM60 are not loaded at all and we see the out of memory issue.
We tested the application by opening and closing the active x control once and then waiting for around 30 seconds and then try launching the active x control. This time it worked. With this we felt the component is taking time to shutdown/unload.
If we try to launch the control before it shuts down, the application is giving that error.
This never happened with VB script code.
**Is there any relation with MSVBVM60.dll with VBScript that makes it to unload faster compared to JScript?**
We could not find any code specific that was different in VB script and JScript.
I need your inputs to think in the right direction. Please help.

Comment: MSVBVM60.dll is the (32-bit) runtime component of VB6 and has nothing to do with VBScript. The OCX has it as a dependency on it because the OCX is written in VB6 so it gets loaded when the OCX gets loaded.

Comment: I'd rewrite all VB6 ActiveX controls into HTML / Javascript components so you don't have any further dependency on VB6. I used to love VB6 but now it's an outdated, unsupported technology and it'll only cause you headaches as you try to make it work with newer tech that was never set up to deal with it.

Comment: JavaScript and JScript use a "fat and sloppy lifetime management" strategy, much like .Net and Java which they ripped off.  This is quaintly called "garbage collection" and is non-deterministic.  Microsoft has chosen to turn their backs on the power and grace that underpins VB6 and VBScript.